# Easy Grade Code with parameters

Tags: c++, parameters

I am trying to make a function that has a int input parameter of a numerical grade and returns a letter grade with either a -, a +, or neither. I know how to do this without the use of reference parameters, but I am trying to use parameters and I am having some difficulty doing so.

One output parameter is the letter grade and the second output parameter is the + or - (+ if missed next grade by 1 or 2 points and - if just made the grade. Here is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void letterGrade (int, float&, float&);

int main(){
    int score;
    float letter;
    float sign;

    cout << "Please input your grade (0-100): ";
    cin >> score;
    cout << endl;

    if (score >=90 && score <=100){
        letter ==  "Letter grade: A"; 

        if (score == 90 ||
            score == 91) {
            sign = "-";
            }
        else if (score == 99 ||
            score == 98) {
            sign == "+";
            }
        else {
            sign == " ";
            }
    }
letterGrade(score, letter, sign);


return 0;
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction that still uses the parameters that would be very helpful.  I think my main problem is I can't figure out how you make something = to a float within the if statement.

Thank you for any help or advise you might have!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the location at which the results will be stored.

So the minimal change to the current code would be to pass in an additional reference to a string that stores the results.

```
void letterGrade (int, float&, float&, std::string&);
```

Then when you call the function:

```
std::string results;//results are stored in here
letterGrade(score, letter, sign, results);//results are passed by reference here
```

Then in the letterGrade function you want to change whatever you were returning to be instead written to the results reference you passed in.

Additionally you are comparing floats with equality. Given that floats are not completely accurately stored in the computer this might end up not giving the behavior you wanted. If you compiled your code with all warnings enabled the compiler would have warned you about this. In future it's a good idea to compile with all warnings as you will quickly get feedback about potential issues. A quick way to fix your code would be to compare with less than and greater than operators. Read this for more info about the floats: https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf